# WPF - RelativeSource in Style

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, styles, relativesource

My target is to bind the **Content**-Property of the *Label* to the **Tag**-Property of the *Elements the Style is applied to*. But my solution doesn't seem to work:

---

My style:

```
<Style
   TargetType="TextBox"
   x:Key="HintedTextBox">
   <Style.Resources>
      <VisualBrush
         AlignmentX="Left"
         AlignmentY="Center"
         Stretch="None"
         x:Key="HintedTextBox_Hint">
         <VisualBrush.Visual>
            <Label
               Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Tag}"
               Foreground="LightGray" />
         </VisualBrush.Visual>
      </VisualBrush>
   </Style.Resources>
   <!-- Triggers -->
</Style>
```

My textbox:

```
<TextBox
   Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=HintedTextBox}"
   x:Name="tbTest" />
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to set the text for `VisualBrush`, that will be displayed in the `TextBox`.

You can do it like this:

```
<TextBox Name="MyTextBox" Tag="MyNewValue" Width="100" Height="25">
    <TextBox.Background>
        <VisualBrush AlignmentX="Left" AlignmentY="Center" Stretch="None">
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <Label Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TextBox}, Path=Tag}" Foreground="LightGray" />
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
    </TextBox.Background>
</TextBox>
```

In order to explain why your example not earned:

**`1.`** As you probably understand, looking at my example, `RelativeSource` must be *not* self, in which case it will point to itself (`VisualBrush`), and the element with the type must be of `TextBox`, located higher in the visual tree.

**`2.`** Binding with `RelativeSource` does not work in resources, because the `Resource` is not part of the visual tree, or part of the template.

**`3.`** In styles this construction will not work, because the `Style` is just the collection of setters, he does not know about control, are there. For this purpose, usually using `DataTemplate` or `ControlTemplate`.

As an alternative, in this case, I suggest using a template for the `TextBox`, which will be registered `VisualBrush`.

Below is my example:

```
<Window.Resources>            
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None" />
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120" />
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20" />
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true" />

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
                    <Border Name="Border" CornerRadius="0" Padding="2" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <VisualBrush AlignmentX="Left" AlignmentY="Center" Stretch="None">
                                <VisualBrush.Visual>
                                    <Label Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Tag}"
                                           Foreground="LightGray" />
                                </VisualBrush.Visual>
                            </VisualBrush>
                        </Border.Background>

                        <ScrollViewer Margin="0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <TextBox Name="MyTextBox" Tag="MyNewValue" Width="100" Height="25" />        
</Grid>
```

**`Output`**

[image]